# Pass a vector to a function input in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, valueerror

I have the following situation:

```
import numpy as np

def func(m):
    M = np.zeros((3,3))
    M[1,1] = 2*m
    return M

print(func(2))
print(func([1,2,3]))
```

The first print function gives me what I want (the (1,1) entry in M becomes 4). But the second one gives me `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`. What I want to do is to print 3 different matrices, one for each value in the array [1,2,3] (so for the 3 matrices the (1,1) entry would be 2, 4 and 6). How can I do this effectively (i.e. without using a for loop)? Thank you!

Comment: There is always a for loop: either explicit, or hidden.

Comment: `print([func(m) for m in [1, 2, 3]])` is one way. Depends a bit on the output style you prefer.

Comment: I am actually a bit confused (not an expert at all!). I thought that for loops are much much slower than calling numpy directly. For example, for a numpy array A, doing B = A**2 is much faster than doing a for loop over A and doing B[i] = A[i]**2. Is this not the case?

Comment: For the example in your comment, `B = A ** 2`, using numpy is faster, because numpy deals with the for loop (probably in C code), and it is faster than a python for loop. However, in your question, there are 3 matrices to create, and they are not put in a single numpy array. Using your method, the 3 matrices have to be created in a python for loop.

Comment: `M[1,1]` is a slot for one float.   `= 2*m`, if `m` is a list of len 3, will be a list of len 6.  It's complaining that it can't put a list in a slot for a float.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to produce a 3d array:

```
In [178]: M = np.zeros((3,3,3),int)

In [179]: M[:,1,1] = np.array([1,2,3])*2

In [180]: M
Out[180]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 2, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 4, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 6, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
```

If you want 3 arrays, you could split that on the first dimension, e.g. `list(M)`.  Three different arrays always requires python level iteration.

re. my comment, beware of list multiplication

```
In [181]: 2*[1,2,3]
Out[181]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

feeding list to an function does not 'automatically' perform an iteration on the elements of the list.  That's also the case if you feed an array.

A list comprehension solution:

```
In [183]: [func(i) for i in [1,2,3]]
Out[183]: 
[array([[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 2., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]),
 array([[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 4., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]),
 array([[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 6., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]])]
```